# About the modification and naming of qiskit parameters？

Tags: qiskit

[image]

Is the parameter angle of the above picture the same, that is, each door rotates by an equal angle? How to assign different parameters to them, such as a[0], a[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coUYX.png) of the same name? Is it possible to change the names of these parameters halfway through? That is, at a certain moment, change a[0], a[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coUYX.png) two different variables into c[0], d[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coUYX.png)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the parameter angle of the above picture the same

Yes. The code assigns the same parameter for all qubits.

> How to assign different parameters to them, such as a[0], a1 of the same name?

You can use [`ParameterVector`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.ParameterVector.html):

```
theta = ParameterVector("θ", 5)
theta_iter = iter(theta)

for i in range(n):
    qc.rz(next(theta_iter), i)
```

The result will be:

[image]

And when you bind the parameters to values, you can assign each parameter its own value:

```
from numpy import pi

bound_circuit = qc.bind_parameters({theta: [0, pi/5, 2*pi/5, 3*pi/5, 4*pi/5]})
```

> Is it possible to change the names of these parameters halfway through?

Yes. You can use one `Parameter` with some qubits, and another one with the other qubits:

```
theta1 = Parameter('θ1')
theta2 = Parameter('θ2')

qc.rz(theta1, range(3))
qc.rz(theta2, range(3, 5))
```

The result:

[image]